# Verifying an Ubuntu installation without an iso file

Tags: kernel, security

I want to verify my kernel.  I found 
[this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto)
explaining how to verify .iso files.

However, I don't have a kernel .iso file.  I only have image files under boot, e.g.

- -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1443719 Aug  9 04:08 abi-4.10.0-32-generic
- -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   204970 Aug  9 04:08 config-4.10.0-32-generic
- -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 43032519 Aug 15 01:00 initrd.img-4.10.0-32-generic
- -rw------- 1 root root  3718993 Aug  9 04:08 System.map-4.10.0-32-generic
- -rw------- 1 root root  7398816 Aug  9 04:08 vmlinuz-4.10.0-32-generic
- -rw------- 1 root root  7400728 Aug 10 23:42 vmlinuz-4.10.0-32-generic.efi.signed

Question: **Is there a way to verify these files?**

Additional information:

- The kernel version given by `uname -a` is  `4.10.0-32-generic`:

  - `Linux user-desktop 4.10.0-32-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 9 09:19:02 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
  - My login screen tells me I am on Ubuntu 16.04.3, differing from the report by`uname -a`

Comment: What makes you think you need to verify your kernel?

Comment: @ubashu - My plan is to set up a routine where I periodically verify the system.  If it's fast then I can just do it on every login.

Comment: So what makes you think you need to verify the system???

Comment: Overall, security seems like a good idea.  However, maybe I'm grabbing the wrong end of the stick?